# C++ 2D Array Map for Tiling Output Inverted

Tags: c++, tile

I have created a 2D array that represents a map for my tiles to be placed:

```
int sMap[12][20] = {
  {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
  {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
  {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
  {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
  {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
  {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
  {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
  {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
  {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1},
  {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
  {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
  {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
};
```

Once my tiles have been loaded in, I use this `function()` to place the tiles:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 12; y++){ //for (int y = 11; y >= 0; y--){
    for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++){ //for (int x = 19; x >= 0; x--){
        if    (sMap[y][x] == 1)
            glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, brick1);
        else if (sMap[y][x] == 2)
            glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, brick2);
        else
            glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, wall );

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(float(x),     float(y), 0.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(float(x + 1), float(y), 0.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(float(x + 1), float(y + 1), 0.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(float(x),     float(y + 1), 0.0f);
        glEnd();
    }
}
```

For some reason, my `Map` is inverted... (So the bottom line of digits in the `map` above is the top line of tiles on screen and the second line up on the `map` is the second line of tiles down on screen).

Its my understanding, you iterate through selecting each digit and assign the correct tile. I've tried changing the `x/y`'s but that rotates the map on screen so its 12 tiles on the `x` and 20 tiles on the `y`.

I want my tiles on screen to represent the map above. Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in the fact that OpenGL actually has the coordinate system that point (0, 0) is in the lower-left part of the viewport. So if you want to represent  that matrix in the code the same way as it should draw, you need to calculate y coordinate for drawing as `<height of viewport> - (calculated y)`. How to get that height - it's up to you, probably you defined it earlier in the code.
For instance, `float(y + 1 + offsety)` will become `float(HEIGHT - (y + 1 + offsety))`.

## EDIT

Oh, I just realized - you have that loop, so, you can put

`for (int y = 11; y >= 0; y--){`

instead existing start of outer loop and that's it. But, anyway, it's good to know that it is NOT accidentally inverted as you thought - it's just up to coordinate system.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to solve the problem... In fact it outputs the exact same view on screen as the previous loops :(

Comment: But hey! Did you do BOTH of that things? If you did, you mirrored it twice. You have do either loop-hack or that subtraction :)

Comment: Yeh = You did both, or one of thing? :) I suggest subtraction, only because of logic - your program will be more readable in comparison with "reversed" loop. But I wonder how it didn't work - it has to work :/

Comment: I tried both loops counting down and both counting up, i also tried `y` counting down and `x` counting up, i also tried `x` counting down and `y` counting up... It just stays mirrored. Im so confused... 
The only height i've specified is the window height of `680` and a viewport start of `0,0`... I'm so confused...

Comment: Do you flush buffer? If you don't, same image can stay for the eternity (I guess, didn't do OpenGL longer time, but I remember things).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26986/discussion-between-ceruleus-and-reanimation)

Comment: Just so people are aware, Subtracting the height as suggested above, solved the problem :) Thanks @ceruleus